# oracle display_raw for varchar size more than 32

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to get the high and low values for oracle table fields using the following SQL:

```
select display_raw(a.low_value,b.data_type) as low_val, display_raw(a.high_value,b.data_type) as high_val
from 
all_tab_col_statistics a, all_tab_cols b 
where
a.owner=b.owner and a.table_name=b.table_name and a.column_name=b.column_name;
```

When the column type is VARCHAR2, above SQL works fine only if the size of the string stored is < 32. If the size of the string stored is > 32 then display_raw returns null.

On further investigation found that display_raw supports only VARCHAR2 of size less then 32.
https://github.com/gregrahn/oracle-scripts/blob/master/display_raw.sql

Is there any reason behind this? And how to overcome this and display low and high values for strings with length more than 32?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 32K is an Oracle restriction on varchar2 length.

Comment: But it not working for strings with size more than just 32 chars.

Comment: O sorry, misread that. The code in your link restricts several variables to 32 chars. Not sure what that function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you increase the size of cv,cnv abd cc variables in the functions?
see code below

```
-- 
--  display_raw.sql
--
--  DESCRIPTION
--    helper function to print raw representation of column stats minimum or maximum
--  
--  Created by Greg Rahn on 2011-08-19.
-- 

create or replace function display_raw (rawval raw, type varchar2)
return varchar2
is
    cn     number;
    cv     varchar2(8192);
    cd     date;
    cnv    nvarchar2(8192);
    cr     rowid;
    cc     char(2000);
    cbf    binary_float;
    cbd    binary_double;
begin
    if (type = 'VARCHAR2') then
        dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(rawval, cv);
        return to_char(cv);
    elsif (type = 'DATE') then
        dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(rawval, cd);
        return to_char(cd);
    elsif (type = 'NUMBER') then
        dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(rawval, cn);
        return to_char(cn);
    elsif (type = 'BINARY_FLOAT') then
        dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(rawval, cbf);
        return to_char(cbf);
    elsif (type = 'BINARY_DOUBLE') then
        dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(rawval, cbd);
        return to_char(cbd);
    elsif (type = 'NVARCHAR2') then
        dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(rawval, cnv);
        return to_char(cnv);
    elsif (type = 'ROWID') then
        dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(rawval, cr);
        return to_char(cr);
    elsif (type = 'CHAR') then
        dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(rawval, cc);
        return to_char(cc);
    else
        return 'UNKNOWN DATATYPE';
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: But this a function in Oracle, not something I defined.

Comment: this is the function from the link https://github.com/gregrahn/oracle-scripts/blob/master/display_raw.sql 
- there's no complex logic there, so, just copy the function source code, make minor changes and recompile it

Comment: Agreed. I have tried it and it works. But I think there should be some intention behind limiting the characters.